# Is it possible to get login name or email from ADFS in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, adfs

I'm working on a project that will be a register over entrepreneurs. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 for the project and on-premise through the customers ADFS for authentication, a group is set up in the AD, and only members of that group can use the application, everything runs on IIS, so far so good, all this works as intended.

The IIS i set up to use a Custom account and anonymous authentication.

My problem is that I want to get the users login name or email from the AD, this is because the customer want different users to have different access in the application, so I need a way to get a unique name/ID or whatever for every user. What I can get is the current users name in the format '*Last name First name*' with

```
ViewBag.currentUser = (Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal).Identity.Name;
```

I can also get all the users in the current group and most of their information (including login name and email) with

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    
     if (ctx != null)
     {
          using (GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SG_GLR")) 
          {
               PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> psr = gp.GetMembers();
               foreach (Principal p in psr)
               {
                    test2.Add(p.Name + " - " + p.SamAccountName + " - " + p.Description + " - " + p.DisplayName + " - " + p.DistinguishedName); 
               }
               ViewBag.test2 = test2;
          }
     }
}
```

I haven't found a way to get that information for just the current logged in user, just the name as I mentioned above. I have tried to use

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value;
```

And

```
WindowsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;
```

I guess these only work with Windows Authentication.

I have also tried

```
User.Identity.Name;
```

And

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

I guess these two are the same as the first one.
I have also tried a bunch of different variations of these, but all I get is either the *Last name First name* or the user that's used for the IIS application pool (I know, I use the Name property that's supposed to return the name, but since I don't find anything else that's close, that's the one I go with for now).

Is it possible to get more information than just the name, if the user is authenticated or authentication type for the current user when ADFS is used for login in this way?

Do I have to change anything in the IIS?

I have probably missed to mention something here, in that case, let me know, otherwise I'm happy for all suggestions, tips and general pointing in any direction!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this myself, to no big suprise at all, the biggest problem was my limited knowledge about how Active Directory works.

I was only looking under the `Identity` parameter.

When I instead used

```
var claims = (Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal).Claims;
```

I got what I wanted, I had to loop through the claims and find the one where the 'Type' paramteter ended with 'upn', since I need to access this information at several places in the code I ended up with this method in the controller:

```
private string GetCurrentUser()
{
    string user = "";
    var claims = (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal).Claims;
    foreach (var claim in claims)
    {
        if(claim.Type.Substring(claim.Type.Length - 3) == "upn")
        {
            user = claim.Value;
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```